# How to keep text selected in a contenteditable element when the element loses focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-wysiwyg

While implementing the [bootstrap-wysiwyg editor](http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/) in a project, I found out I can't reproduce how adding a link works in that example editor.

In the example you can first select text in the editable area, then open the add hyperlink dropdown, enter a URL, and click Add, all the while keeping your original selection in the contenteditable element.

However, try as I might, whenever I click in the URL input in my implementation, the selection is lost, and the add hyperlink functionality wont work. How is it done in the bootstrap-wysiwyg demo? I've even tried using the same, older versions of jQuery and Bootstrap as in the demo, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Here's a snippet:

```js
$('#editor').wysiwyg();

$('.dropdown-menu input').click(function() {
    return false;
})
.change(function () {
    $(this).parent('.dropdown-menu')
    .siblings('.dropdown-toggle')
    .dropdown('toggle');
})
.keydown('esc', function () {
    this.value='';
    $(this).change();
});

$('#addBtn').click(function() {
    document.execCommand('createLink', false, $('#linkInput').val());
});
```

```css
#editor {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.0.2/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/external/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
<script src="http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap-wysiwyg.js"></script>
<div id="editor">
  Edit me!
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Hyperlink">
        <i class="icon-link"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
     <input id="linkInput" placeholder="URL" type="text" data-edit="createLink">
     <button id="addBtn" class="btn" type="button">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the same in a fiddle if you prefer that:

http://jsfiddle.net/Schlaus/sydrb05c/1/

Please note that while it might at first appear that the add url functionality doesn't work at all, it does but it requires the editor to have focus. Thus, first fill in an URL, then focus the editor and select some text, then open the dropdown and click again on Add.

Answer (score 1):

If you examine the source you will find that every time a `mouseup`, `keyup` or `mouseout` event fires on the editor div they snatch a copy of the range. This allows the selection to be recreated prior to acting on it.

Around line 300 you'll find this

```
editor.attr('contenteditable', true)
.on(namespaceEvents('mouseup keyup mouseout'), function () {
  saveSelection();
  updateToolbar();
});
```

Around line 248 you'll find this

```
toolbar.find('[data-toggle=dropdown]').click(restoreSelection);
```

This works erratically on IE because it's timing sensitive and slow DOM updates (eg show/hide a dropdown of typefaces as per the standard demo) will muck things up. You can fix it simply by allowing the DOM updates to finish before you try to restore the selection, like this:

```
toolbar.find('[data-toggle=dropdown]').click(function () {
  setTimeout(restoreSelection, 20);
});
```

As for the hyperlink stuff, I'm working on that right now and I'll update this answer shortly.